# Suppress output from an interact() widget

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

I am using a widget to parametrise the generation of some data. I would like to capture the data, without outputting it. Is this possible? Adding `;` after `interact()` doesn't work. Example:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed

def generate_data(n, p, s):
    return np.random.negative_binomial(n, p, s)

w_n = widgets.IntSlider(min=1, max=10000, step=1)
w_p = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0.01, max=1, step = 0.01)
w_s = widgets.IntSlider(min=500,max=10000,step=50)

data = interact(generate_data, n = w_n, p = w_p, s = w_s);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning a value in `generate_data()`, you could modify a global variable. It avoids printing the output, and you can use `val` later in your code.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed
import numpy as np

val = None
def generate_data(n, p, s):
    global val
    val = np.random.negative_binomial(n, p, s)

w_n = widgets.IntSlider(min=1, max=10000, step=1)
w_p = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0.01, max=1, step = 0.01)
w_s = widgets.IntSlider(min=500,max=10000,step=50)

interact(generate_data, n = w_n, p = w_p, s = w_s)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have submitted a pull request to ipywidgets that addresses this problem:

https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets/pull/712

The changes are actually very simple. With this version, you would simply pass an extra kwarg to `interact`:

```
data = interact(generate_data, n = w_n, p = w_p, s = w_s,
                __output_result=False)
```